# How to use get_random_bytes() in linux kernel module?

Tags: c, linux

I have made simple kernel module.

```
void cb_funct(unsigned long arg)    // callback function.
{
    int rand;
    get_random_bytes(&rand, sizeof(rand));
    rand%=250;

    seq_printf(m, "random number : %d\n", rand);
    ...
}
```

I printed out rand variable using seq_printf function.

cb_funct function is called five times.

Below is the result.

> random number : 66
>
> random number : -5
>
> random number : 135
>
> random number : 178
>
> random number : -42

Why negative variable is printed out?

How to use **get_random_bytes** function in linux?

Comment: Probably because `rand` contains a negative number.

Comment: Oh, that function could generate negative number as well. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Well, it generates random bytes. `int` is a signed type, so by filling it with random bytes I'd expect negative values to show up.

Comment: Adding to @melpomene's comment, perhaps printf rand as unsigned int? as "%u" instead of "%d", and declare rand as "unsigned".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes sense that you are seeing negative numbers. Assuming that sizeof(int) = 4 bytes, you are asking `get_random_bytes` to fill up 4 bytes of random numbers starting at address `&rand`. If the most significant bit for the most significant byte happens to get a 1, then rand will be a negative number. For signed variables (such as int), the most significant bit declares sign. 
There are multiple things that you can do if that is a problem:

- Use an unsigned variable (`unsigned int` or `uint32_t`, for example). When you print it, remember to use %u or 0x%x.
- Mask out the most significant bit after calling get_random_bytes. Something like this (again, assuming size(int) is 4 bytes): `rand &= 0x7FFFFFFF`. This will get you a positive random number.
- ask `get_random_bytes` to fill up only three bytes, so it won't fill up the most significant byte. But your random number will be in range 0 - 0xFFFFFF instead of 0 - 0xFFFFFFFF. And you should initialize your variable to 0 first. You could do: `int rand = 0; get_random_bytes(&rand, sizeof(int)-1);`

Comment: .@JayMedina: How to get this working for random values between 0 and 1?

Comment: To get random value between 0 and 1, you can first get a random number b/w 0 to 100 and divide the latter by 100. In this random number generated would have 2 decimal digit precision.

Comment: "ask get_random_bytes to fill up only three bytes, so it won't fill up the most significant byte." is a faulty approach as it assumes a certain endian.  Code might not fill the least significant byte

Comment: Rather than try to co-ordinate object and type, just use the object.  `get_random_bytes(&rand, sizeof(int)-1);` --> `get_random_bytes(&rand, sizeof(rand) - 1);` - OP had that right with `get_random_bytes(&rand, sizeof(rand));`.